# postgreSQL : oracle sqlerrm equivalent of postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL. I have experience in oracle. In oracle , to find the exact error, I use code 'dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm)' . Here I have a postgresql function returning an integer value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_sqltest(
  p_id integer)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

  COST 100
  VOLATILE 

 AS $BODY$ 
 Declare
   n integer;
 begin  

     select off_id into n from office 
       where per_id=p_id;

     return n ;

 exception when others then

     return -1;

 end;

 $BODY$;

 ALTER FUNCTION public.fn_sqltest(character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I call this function as below

```
DO $$ 

DECLARE
  ae integer;

BEGIN 

  ae:=fn_sqltest(10);
  RAISE NOTICE 'exception: % %  ', sqlstate ,  sqlerrm ;
  RAISE NOTICE 'Return value is: % ', ae;

END $$;
```

and I get the error

> ERROR: column "sqlstate" does not exist

How can I show the exact error message like sqlerrm in oracle.

Comment: See [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57089146/postgresql-oracle-sqlerrm-equivalent-of-postgres) in particular section  __43.6.8.1. Obtaining Information About an Error__ concerning GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS

Comment: Thanks.link was not working though I was  able to get it through the section you specified. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the function and wrote a code in function exception section

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_sqltest(
p_id integer)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 

 AS $BODY$ 
 Declare
   n integer;
   text_var1 text;
   text_var2 text;
   text_var3 text;
 begin  

   select off_id into n from office 
     where per_id=p_id;

   return n ;

 exception when others then

   GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS text_var1 = MESSAGE_TEXT,
                      text_var2 = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
                      text_var3 = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;

   RAISE NOTICE 'Return value is: %  % %',text_var1 , text_var2, text_var3;

   return -1;

end;

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.fn_sqltest(character varying)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Another method is by changing the return type. I changed the return type to text and rewrite the exception section code as below

```
return sqlerrm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike PL/SQL, in PL/pgSQL SQLSTATE and SQLERRM are not defined outside an exception handler. See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING), section "Obtaining Information About An Error".

This also means that you can't get SQLSTATE and SQLERRM of a successful operation, unlike PL/SQL.

So, if you want to use these special variables outside an exception handler, you have to store them in variables.

I don't know how would you like to return them from the function. I can demonstrate this idea inside your function code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_sqltest(
  p_id integer)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

  COST 100
  VOLATILE 

 AS $BODY$ 
 Declare
   n integer;
   v_sqlerrm text;
   v_sqlstate text;
begin
 begin  

     select off_id into n from office 
       where per_id=p_id;

     return n ;

 exception when others then
    
     v_sqlerrm := sqlerrm;
     v_sqlstate := sqlstate;
      
 end;

 RAISE NOTICE 'exception: % %  ', v_sqlstate ,  v_sqlerrm ;

 return -1;

end;

 $BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but just for the record: The easiest way to output the state and message of error is to raise them from within the exception clause. You don't need to declare extra variables.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_sqltest(p_id integer)
    RETURNS integer
AS $$ 
DECLARE
    n   integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT off_id
        INTO n
        FROM office
        WHERE per_id = p_id;
    RETURN n;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'exception: % - %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
    RETURN -1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```